# How to link plotted positions on a 2-D graph

Tags: matlab

I have the following code to plot some points on a 2-D x,y coordinate plane:

```
A=[1, 1; 1, 5; 3, 9; 4, 2; 4, 6; 6, 2; 7, 6; 6, 9; 9, 9];
figure
plot(A(:,1),A(:,2),'r.','LineWidth',2,'MarkerSize',10);
axis([0 10 0 10]);
str=num2str(A);
text(A(:,1)*1.02,A(:,2)*1.02,str);
```

However, my problem is I will like to link each point to every other point, to form a mesh.

Can anyone please assist with this problem.

Comment: Is something like this you need? http://i.imgur.com/ewNrLJW.png or is in a grid format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can double loop through the rows of `A` and draw a line between each pair. If you add these lines to the end of your code:

```
hold on
for ii = 1:(size(A, 1) - 1)
    for jj = (ii + 1):size(A, 1)
        line([A(ii, 1), A(jj, 1)], [A(ii, 2), A(jj, 2)])
    end
end
```

You will get the plot with each point connected to all the other points:

[image]

Comment: Even if the code does what is desired, I would recommend for code clarity changing the syntax `ii + 1:size(A, 1)` to `(ii+1):size(A, 1)`. Even if parenthesis are not required, having the `+` separated with spaces and the `1:size(A, 1)` together, might be confused with the operation `ii + (1:size(A, 1))` (first creating the vector and then adding ii). Again it's just for code clarity.

Comment: Thanks for noting. I applied your suggestion.